# React js throwing Firestore Missing or insufficient permissions even after Rules are public

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Error in console by firebase firestore]

[image: I changed my security rules to public but still getting this error]

**Following is code for my firestore writing**

When I try to write to my Firestore database, I get `Missing or insufficient permissions` error. Even after I changed the rules to `public`.

iam using npm firebase package in my project

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { myFirebaseStorage, myFirebaseFirestore, timestamp } from '../firebase/config';

const useStorage = (file) => {

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);



useEffect(() => {

    const storageRef = myFirebaseStorage.ref(file.name);

     //database collection reference
    const collectionRef = myFirebaseFirestore.collection('images');

    storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {

        let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;

        setProgress(percentage);

    },
        (err) => {
            setError(err);
        },
        async () => {

            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
            console.log(" Image URL: ", url);
            const createdAt = timestamp();

             //writing data to firestore

            collectionRef.add({ url: url, createdAt: createdAt })
                .then((docRef) => {
                    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });

                





            collectionRef
                .get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    // allowed for an admin user
                    console.log("got it ")
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // a non-admin user is denied list permission
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
            setUrl(url);

        }
    )
}, [file])

return (
    { progress, url, error }
)}export default useStorage
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you try to write to a Firestore database?

Comment: @farid-shumbar  added code file code ..have look,thankyou

Answer (score 0):

As you also reference your Firebase Storage, you'll need to set up [Firebase Storage Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) as well for the write to work.